# Mastermind Scoring Algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, scoring

I am working on a client/server mastermind game in C and I have finished so far. My programs are working and it solves the secret in average 6-7 guesses. Then I was looking over the internet and found Donals Knuths approach:

1. Create a set S of remaining possibilities (at this point there are
   1296). The first guess is aabb.
2. Remove all possibilities from S that would not give the same score
   of colored and white pegs if they were the answer.
3. For each possible guess (not necessarily in S) calculate how many
   possibilities from S would be eliminated for each possible
   colored/white score. The score of the guess is the least of such
   values. Play the guess with the highest score (minimax).
4. Go back to step 2 until you have got it right.

What I have to say here is that I use 5 positions and 8 colors.

As I am trying to optimize my program I have a hard time understanding how step 3, in particular the calculation of what guess would eliminate the most possibilities, would look like.

What I know is that I have to look at every element and compare it to every other, but I am not sure how to compare it, since I don't have any white/black values for it. And I am wondering how could I tell what entry that meets certain **conditions** would eliminate the maximum possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discuss the algorithm and give an implementation (in Scheme, not C) at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/11/20/master-mind-part-2/). The tricky part is this predicate in the minimax function:

```
(or (< size min-size)
    (and (= size min-size)
         (member (car ps) pool)
         (not (member min-probe pool))))
```

You'll have to read the entire blog post to figure out the details, but basically this implements Knuth's "subject to" requirement: if the probe is a new minimum, or if it is equal to the current minimum, is a member of the pool, and the current minimum is not a member of the pool, keep it as the new minimum, otherwise loop to the next probe.

Comment: Thank you! I found what I was looking for on your blog, when I saw the table I realized that you are just counting the possibilities, that are left, when you lock one color in place. Is that all there is to it? I already thought of that but wasn't sure, since it only treats the "is the color in the right position" condition and ignores the "does it contain these colors" condition.

Comment: @Nurfed: You're new here. Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you find an answer useful, you should give it an upvote by clicking on the up arrow to the left of the answer. If, as in this case, you asked the original question, you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I can't upvote until my reputation reaches 15. I would have checked that but I thought you might respond to my comment first!